# DSX scheduled jobs do not refresh internal notebooks

Tags: data-science-experience

when creating a scheduled job, only the notebooks that are shared (in a public link) are updated every hour but not any of the notebooks that that are viewed internally, that is, by the collaborators of the project. Is this planned to be fixed at some point?

Comment: That's something you should report to or ask IBM directly, not a question for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

How is viewing a notebook supposed to update anything? I assume that you mean updates from internal collaborators are not picked up by the scheduled job.

Ask the internal collaborators to use "Save Version" instead of "Save" when they want their changes to be picked up by the scheduled job. Sharing a notebook implicitly saves a version instead of a snapshot. But you can do it explicitly as well, without sharing.